# Twilio Call Masking Similar to Uber

Tags: parse-platform, twilio

I need to use twilio call masking similar to how uber does.  I need to grab and available number and attach it to a transaction for a period of time.  I got basic TwimXML working to deliver a message but how do I connect two numbers on the fly?

I'm working in iOS and Android with Parse.com serving as a temporary back end.  Since these are mobile applications I'm hoping to use the native telephone and messaging applications.

My assumption is that I need to grab a number from the number pool.  Assign a forwarding number to it.  And return that number to my application in the success block of the promise.  Then send that number to the telephone/message app.  The part I'm not sure about is how to set up a forwarding number on my Twilio number with the rest api.

Any direction here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your assumptions are mostly correct, but as you point out, you're missing the bit about assigning the forwarding number.

If you've used TwiML to reply to an incoming message you are on the way though.

What you need is an endpoint that you can set as the Voice URL for the number you purchase through Twilio. With that endpoint you need to return TwiML that forwards the call onto the right number. That TwiML would look a bit like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>ONWARD_NUMBER</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

In order to return that TwiML, you would need to set up a relationship in your database between the two users' phone numbers and the Twilio phone number such that when you receive a call from one of the numbers to the Twilio number, you can look up the other number in the database and use that in the forwarding TwiML.

That is a brief description of how this is supposed to work. There is a longer description of how to achieve this sort of system in our [Masked Phone Numbers tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/ruby/rails). Sadly the tutorial is not currently available in Node.js, but if you read through the instructions you should be able to follow the flow of the application.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Here's the node.js code to output that. `var twilio = require('twilio');  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse(); twiml.dial({callerId:'A twilio number you own'}, 'The number you want to call');  response.type('text/xml');  response.send(twiml.toString());`

Comment: hello @philnash i want to implement in android app so for that what i need